# Button Translation on Salesforce Survey

Tags: salesforce-survey

As you can see in the image there is no translation for the button in the Survey.

As the button is not available in the Languages tab to be translated, does anybody know how to translate this literal?

Thank you very much in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@esteve If you are translating your Survey to any Salesforce Supported languages, then buttons will get translated out of the box and you need not worry about it.

You can check more about it in [Salesforce Survey help guide.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=task_translate_surveys.htm&type=5)

Also, you can check out this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/LSeBRsmOgeA) which explains it in detail with examples.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is translated out of the box according to the chosen user language.
The same for the guest surveys: Buttons are translated to the chosen language on the first page.